# How to run *.FLV file in SharePoint 2010

Tags: solution-package, video

I'm looking for the free tool or free code in order to run *.FLV file in SharePoint 2010. Does Media Web Part support FLV video?

Thanks and Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we're using flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/) for some webcasts that we have in .flv format on our SharePoint 2010 based intranet (also used it under SharePoint 2007). Quite easy to set up, several customisation possibilities.

Comment: Yes it is! I had it set up within 5 minutes, and then did some finetuning to make it look nicer. Look at the demos and the documentation on the site